# Usage of 'the most important being...'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, gerunds, progressive-aspect

> Paper is made from many materials, the most important being trees.

It is from my TOEFL preparation book and I know what it means throughout seeing the translation in my language. But I don't understand that why it put 'being' after adjective which is important. I think that the meaning of sentence should be:

> Paper is made from many materials and the important thing is trees.

not:

> Being trees is important material for making paper.

Do you understand my question? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

> *Paper is made from many materials, **the most important** being trees.*

You're right about this:

> I think that the meaning of sentence should be 'paper is made from many materials and the important thing is trees.'

But you're wrong about this:

> I don't understand that why it put 'being' after adjective which is important.

Here, ***the most important*** is a noun phrase even without any noun in it, and the noun phrase acts as the subject of the participial clause "the most important being trees."

Answer (score 0):

**Paper is made from many materials, the most important being trees.**

Above sentences are linked. First one says that paper are made from more than one material. So there should be multiple sources.(usually two or more). From that set of materials, **Trees** are the mostly used, often used material.

in the sentence, *most important being trees* , means, From the each material that can be used to make paper, Trees are the most common and widely used material.

If you say,

> *paper is made from many materials and the important thing is trees.*

It means paper id made from few materials and trees are important for some related reason.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are very close with this:

> paper is made from many materials and the important thing is trees

To improve:

> paper is made from many materials and the most important *[material]* **is being** trees

Present continuous is used because the action in not only generic, but it is still true while speaking.

After we lose `is`, we get the original sentence.

It can work equally well reversed (with slightly modified grammar):

> paper is made from many materials, trees **being** the most important *[material]*

As to the **why** of this, maybe a better prepared friend can help.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of  Reduced Relative Clauses. Remove the relative pronoun; remove ‎the verb 'be'; Place the present participle phrase after the modified noun: ‎
‎'Paper is made from many materials of which trees are the most important. ‎
‎ '‎